# Field 'Invoice_Date' cannot be modified

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

i have the following ms access 2003 table:

```
Invoice_Master
(
   Invoice_Id  Autonumber,
   Customer_Id  integer,
   Invoice_Date  Date/Time not null,
.
.
.
);
```

and following code (Delphi 7)

```
procedure TfmInvoiceMaster.adoMasterEditNewRecord(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  inherited;
  adoMasterEditInvoice_Date.AsDateTime := Date;
end;
```

when i try to add a new record i end with exception error sys:

> Field 'Invoice_Date' cannot be modified.

pls what is wrong

Comment: are the other fields writeable? (maybe the whole dataset is read-only). p.s. the `inherited` call in adoMasterEditNewRecord is unusual

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. :)

You should be using the `AfterEdit` event instead. From  the help file on `TDataSet.AfterEdit`:

> Write an AfterEdit event handler to take specific action immediately after dataset enters edit mode. AfterEdit is called by Edit after it enables editing of a record, recalculates calculated fields, and calls the data event handler to process a record change.

Use it like this:

```
procedure TfmInvoiceMaster.adoMasterAfterEdit(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  // No inherited call! This is an event handler, not an overridden method
  adoMasterEditInvoice_Date.AsDateTime := Date;
end;
```

From your text, though, you seem to be wanting to do it when a record is inserted, not edited ("when i try to add a new record i end with exception error sys:"). If that's the case, use `AfterInsert` the same exact way:

```
procedure TfmInvoiceMaster.adoMasterAfterInsert(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  // No inherited call! This is an event handler, not an overridden method
  adoMasterEditInvoice_Date.AsDateTime := Date;
end;
```

Comment: i want the user see the date before he post the record, i used inherited for other purpose not mentioned here.. thanks for help

Comment: @Ken White, I disagree. `OnNewRecord` is in fact the right event handler to set defaults when using Insert/Append

Comment: ...But I also fail to understand the `inherited` part. could the OP explain? is `TfmInvoiceMaster` sub-classed?

Comment: @kobik: OK. We disagree. :) The docs specifically say that `AfterInsert` is called immediately after a record is inserted (which means it's in editing mode and can be updated), and this event has worked just fine since Delphi 1 for me. I don't see any benefit to using `OnNewRecord` instead; AFAICT, for use in initializing new records they're equally functional. :) I don't understand the OP's use of `inherited` either, which is why I specifically mentioned NOT using it in my answer.

Comment: @BlueOcean, the user *will* see the data before it's posted. Read the documentation - `AfterInsert` is called immediately after the new record is added, and will be there before the user sees the data entry controls. Of course, you could try it really quickly for yourself and see if it works or not. :)

Comment: @KenWhite, Let me rephrase :) I disagree on "You're doing it wrong". `AfterInsert` should work just as well as `OnNewRecord`. From the docs: `Write an OnNewRecord event handler to take specific actions as an application inserts or appends a new record. OnNewRecord is called as part of the insert or append process. An application might use the OnNewRecord event to set initial values for a record or as a way of implementing cascading insertions in related datasets.`. I'm 99.99% sure that the field is read-only so he will get the same error with `AfterInsert`.

Comment: @kobik, OK. :) Fair enough. I saw the `Edit` in the event name instead of the `NewRecord` part; that's what my "wrong" was referencing. I've always had the `AfterInsert` work just fine, and just noticed that `OnNewRecord` references `AfterInsert` in the docs also, so they might be fairly equivalent. (Didn't check the source to find out what the diff might be, though; I'd suspect without looking that they're called in succession if they're assigned.) I guess we'll have to wait for the OP to tell us what the problem actually is, though.